# Setting jquery mobile minimum page height for a page with a static footer

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Since the fixed position footer is still a bit jumpy in 1.0b1, I would like to use a statically positioned footer on my pages.  However, the footer does not automatically pin to the bottom of the screen as it does when fixed, when a particular page has less than a full screen of content.

does anyone know the preferred way to set the min height of the content div to force the footer to the bottom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Providing your footer has the `data-role=footer` attribute and your pages have `data-role=page`...

```
[data-role=page]{height: 100% !important; position:relative !important;}
[data-role=footer]{bottom:0; position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; width:100%;}
```

That's how I've done it in a project of mine